# Scanner debugging

Tags: java

I have some issue using `Scanner`
That's the problematic code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Chose 1 or 2 = ");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        byte a = scan.nextByte();
        scan.close();
        if (a==1) HW();
        else if (a==2) {
            System.out.print("Calculation program ... !\nInput Number 1st number = ");
            Scanner Catch = new Scanner(System.in);
            int x = Catch.nextInt();
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.print("Input Operand +,-,*,/ = ");
            Scanner Catchc = new Scanner (System.in);
            char z = Catchc.next().charAt(0);
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.print("Input 2nd number = ");
            Scanner Catch2 = new Scanner (System.in);
            int y = Catch2.nextInt();
            Catch.close();
            Catchc.close();
            Catch2.close();
        calc(x,y,z);
        }
        else System.out.println("Please input number 1 or 2 ");
    }
}
```

Thats a simple calculator and i got no errors and the program didn't terminate but it do debug instead. It shows "no such element exception"

Calc method:

```
public static void calc(int x, int y, char z) {
  int result;
  result = 0;
  switch (z) {
   case '+': result = x + y;
   case '-': result = x - y;
   case '/': result = x / y;
   case '*': result = x * y;
  }
  System.out.println("Result of " + x + " " + z + " " + y + " is..." + " " + result);
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with `Scanner`s, you should only create 1 and NEVER close them until your program is done. This is because closing a scanner closes the passed in `InputStream`, and this inputstream is the input of your program, so you program doesn't cant recieve anymore input after that points.

Rewrite your code to only create 1 scanner, and pass that to other functions:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Chose 1 or 2 = ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    byte a = scan.nextByte();
    if (a==1) 
        HW();
    else if (a==2) {
        System.out.print("Calculation program ... !\nInput Number 1st number = ");
        int x = scan.nextInt();
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("Input Operand +,-,*,/ = ");
        char z = scan.next().charAt(0);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("Input 2nd number = ");
        int y = scan.nextInt();
        calc(x,y,z);
    }
    else 
        System.out.println("Please input number 1 or 2 ");
}
```

Comment: This is helpful, Thank you @Ferrybig

Comment: I created a commandline interface prog that has multiple procedures that potentially ask for input. I was initially closing individual scanners that worked at first then suddenly after an update began throwing errors about closed pipes, etc. This fixed it for me, just create one scanner and reuse it till you exit the program then close it in the cleanup code.